# Frequency of a sequence of values in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan, frequency

I'm new with pandas and have a dataset like following

```
id  values  exp
z1  s1  NaN
z1  s2  NaN
z1  s3  NaN
z1  s4  v
z1  s2  NaN
z1  s3  NaN
z1  s4  w
z2  s1  NaN
z2  s5  NaN
z2  s4  w
z3  s1  NaN
z3  s2  NaN
z3  s3  NaN
z3  s4  v
z4  s1  NaN
z4  s2  NaN
z4  s4  w
```

and I want to get an output like (Table2), showing frequency of a sequence terminated by a value in `exp` column

```
id    seq          exp
z1  s1-s2-s3-s4     v
z1  s2-s3-s4        w
z2  s1-s5-s4        w
z3  s1-s2-s3-s4     v
z4  s1-s2-s4        w
```

The final outcome I want is following, but I can work with Table2 to get there.

```
seq     count
s1-s2-s3-s4   2
s2-s3-s4      1
s1-s5-s4      1
s1-s2-s4      1
```

Looking for guidance to solving this with pandas/ python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.bfill.html) for replace `NaN` back filling, then `groupby` by column `id` and `Series` created by `bfill` with `apply` `join`. Last [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
print (df.exp.bfill())
0     v
1     v
2     v
3     v
4     w
5     w
6     w
7     w
8     w
9     w
10    v
11    v
12    v
13    v
14    w
15    w
16    w
Name: exp, dtype: object
```

```
df = df.groupby(['id', df.exp.bfill()])['values'].apply('-'.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   id exp       values
0  z1   v  s1-s2-s3-s4
1  z1   w     s2-s3-s4
2  z2   w     s1-s5-s4
3  z3   v  s1-s2-s3-s4
4  z4   w     s1-s2-s4

df1 = df['values'].value_counts().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['seq','counts']
print (df1)
           seq  counts
0  s1-s2-s3-s4       2
1     s2-s3-s4       1
2     s1-s2-s4       1
3     s1-s5-s4       1
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael !!! This works. I have a visualization question but I would ask it separately. Thanks again.